# Draw image as a polygon

Tags: java, swing, awt, drawing, polygon

I'm trying to draw an image as a polygon in Swing but I don't know how. Now I 
 only have code to draw filled polygon. This is not a cropped image, it is distorted.

***What I need (Polygon with texture):***

[image: Polygon with texture]

***What I have - Filled polygon***

[image: Filled Polygon]

```
gr.fillPolygon(x_points, y_points, points.length);
```

Comment: Can you post the code on here?

Comment: Already posted code

Comment: I do not need crop the image, I need to distort it

Comment: You'd need a `Paint` subclass that will determine the color at each pixel of the fill (similar to `LinearGradientPaint` or `CircularGradientPaint`). However I searched a bit and it doesn't look like anyone ever made that and making it yourself is not easy. I think no one made that because they'd use OpenGL or similar.

Comment: so to ensure am understanding this right before go on and answer , what you want is to fill a polygon with an image ? or  fill it with a texture ?@Хуски

Comment: I need to fill polygon with the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to render 3D is using [JOGL](https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) library which uses OpenGL to render in JPanel.